# argocd sync failure hook not working for sending notification

Tags: yaml, continuous-integration, argocd, argo-workflows

configuration used for configuring synchook failure job

```
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: failurehook
  annotations:
    argocd.argoproj.io/hook: SyncFail
    argocd.argoproj.io/hook-delete-policy: HookSucceeded
spec:
  template:
      #calling a container to send mail
```

K8 job not getting triggered when LAST SYNC RESULT in argocd sync gets failed. Followed below documentation for configuring
https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/resource_hooks/

Argo version used: v2.2.5
Whether hook was deprecated any alternates for handling these failure cases?